# tty_flip_buffer_push() sends data back to itself

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to run tiny_tty in LDD3. When I use "cat /dev/ttty0" to read from it, there is no output and the command is blocked.

Checking the trace, I notice both tty_insert_flip_char() and tty_flip_buffer_push() are called. However, the data is not sent to the user by tty core. Instead, it is sent back to the tiny_tty driver's tiny_write() callback function. What is wrong there?

The kernel version is 2.6.32-61-generic.

Here is the trace

```
tiny_open()
tiny_timer() tty_flip_buffer_push()
tiny_write - 48
```

Here is code

```
static void tiny_timer(unsigned long timer_data)
{
    struct tiny_serial *tiny = (struct tiny_serial *)timer_data;
    struct tty_struct *tty_st_p;
    struct tty_port *port;
    int i;
    char data[1] = {TINY_DATA_CHARACTER};
    int data_size = 1;

    if (!tiny)
        return;

    tty_st_p = tiny->tty_tse_p;

    if (!tty_buffer_request_room(tty_st_p, 1))
        tty_flip_buffer_push(tty_st_p);

    tty_insert_flip_char(tty_st_p, 'H', TTY_NORMAL);

    tty_flip_buffer_push(tty_st_p);
    printk(KERN_INFO "tiny_timer() tty_flip_buffer_push()\n");

    /* resubmit the timer again */
    tiny->timer->expires = jiffies + DELAY_TIME;
    add_timer(tiny->timer);
}

static int tiny_open(struct tty_struct *tty_st_p, struct file *file)
{
    struct tiny_serial *tiny;
    struct timer_list *timer;
    int index;

    /* initialize the pointer in case something fails */
    tty_st_p->driver_data = NULL;

    /* get the serial object associated with this tty pointer */
    index = tty_st_p->index;
    tiny = tiny_table[index];

    if (tiny == NULL) {
        /* first time accessing this device, let's create it */
        tiny = kmalloc(sizeof(*tiny), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!tiny)
            return -ENOMEM;

        sema_init(&tiny->sem, 1);
        tiny->open_count = 0;
        tiny->timer = NULL;

        tiny_table[index] = tiny;
    }

    down(&tiny->sem);

    /* save our structure within the tty structure */
    tty_st_p->driver_data = tiny;
    tiny->tty_tse_p = tty_st_p;

    ++tiny->open_count;
    if (tiny->open_count == 1) {
        /* this is the first time this port is opened */
        /* do any hardware initialization needed here */

        /* create our timer and submit it */
        if (!tiny->timer) {
            timer = kmalloc(sizeof(*timer), GFP_KERNEL);
            if (!timer) {
                up(&tiny->sem);
                return -ENOMEM;
            }
            tiny->timer = timer;
            init_timer(tiny->timer);
        }

        tiny->timer->data = (unsigned long )tiny;
        tiny->timer->expires = jiffies + DELAY_TIME;
        tiny->timer->function = tiny_timer;
        printk(KERN_INFO, "tiny_open()\n");
        add_timer(tiny->timer);
    }

    up(&tiny->sem);

    return 0;
}

static int tiny_write(struct tty_struct *tty_st_p,
                      const unsigned char *buffer, int count)
{
    struct tiny_serial *tiny = tty_st_p->driver_data;
    int i;
    int retval = -EINVAL;

    if (!tiny)
        return -ENODEV;

    down(&tiny->sem);

    if (!tiny->open_count)
        /* port was not opened */
        goto exit;

    /* fake sending the data out a hardware port by
    * writing it to the kernel debug log.
    */
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s - ", __FUNCTION__);
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printk("%02x ", buffer[i]);
    printk("\n");
    retval = count;

exit:
    up(&tiny->sem);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: i am also doing the same and facing same issue not able to get output on user terminal did you solved this issue if yes then how ?

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal device has ECHO enabled. You can turn it off (and control other flags as well) with `stty` command:

```
stty -F /dev/ttty0 -echo
```

or use a proper terminal emulation program like `picocom` or `minicom`.