# linux kernel tty driver can you turn off echo by default in the code?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Related to this question: [tty-flip-buffer-push-sends-data-back-to-itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234117/tty-flip-buffer-push-sends-data-back-to-itself)

So I had the same issue, where I have written a driver and in my tty callback code that writes back out of the tty to the user (who is running `cat /dev/mytty`).

When I write to the tty it loops back and cat should print it out. However since echo it on it goes around in a loop forever. Entering the command `stty -F /dev/mytty -echo` fixes that.

So my question is in my driver code is there a setting that I can change to not default to echo on? Maybe in the `tty_probe(...)` or `tty_set_operations(...)` functinos?

Comment: This sort of policy should really not be decided by a random TTY driver.

Comment: @IanAbbott this is for my specific tty driver : )

Comment: But do you have a specific reason for your driver to deviate from the norm? After all, the user can easily disable echo if they need to do strange things like `cat /dev/mytty`. Perhaps you are not using the device as a general purpose TTY port?

Comment: @IanAbbott I was just trying to test it using things like `cat`, but I think once I am past the testing phase then it should not matter since I would be communicating to the tty programatically (e.g. with posix `open()`/`close()` etc...). I think I would prefer it to be set with echo off for `mytty` device since it serves no purpose. But I can always remove that bit of code. So in summary - other then for early testing, no, I have no specific reason - except laziness?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off echo before the call to `tty_set_operations()` with something like the following:

```
tty_driver->init_termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
```